# How to deal with long conditional expression in Github Actions Workflow

Tags: github-actions

How to best deal with long conditional expressions in GitHub Actions Workflow?

I have a workflow that I want to run in 2 cases:

1. when a pull request is closed
2. when a comment containing a specific string is created on a pull request

This leads to a workflow definition with a long `if` expression:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [ closed ]
  issue_comment:
    types: [ created ]
jobs:
  do:
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' || (github.event_name == 'issue_comment' && github.event.issue.pull_request && contains(github.event.comment.body, 'specific string')) }}
    steps:
      ...
```

A solution I see is to split the workflow in 2 definitions, but I'd like to avoid this due to DRY.

Ideas I searched for, but did not find working solutions for:

- define the expression on multiple lines
- split the if in multiple if expressions

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's easy to define the expression on multiple lines using yaml multiline strings (ref: https://yaml-multiline.info/). For example:

```yaml
if: >  # Either `>`, `>-`, `|`, `|-` will be OK
  github.event_name == 'pull_request' ||
  (
    github.event_name == 'issue_comment' &&
    github.event.issue.pull_request &&
    contains(github.event.comment.body, 'specific string')
  )
```

To use expression syntax (`${{ }}`), the final new line should be trimmed. Because expression should end with `}}`, no trailing white space.

```
if: >-  # Use `>-` or `|-`
  ${{
    github.event_name == 'pull_request' ||
    (
      github.event_name == 'issue_comment' &&
      github.event.issue.pull_request &&
      contains(github.event.comment.body, 'specific string')
    )
  }}
```

See https://github.com/AllanChain/test-action-if/blob/main/.github/workflows/test-if.yml for the demo.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Note, that the expression syntax (`${{ }}`) may only be omitted if no operators are used. In this case they are, so it should be something like: 
`if: > ${{ ... }}`

Comment: @Korthout Well, interesting. I omitted `${{ }}` without problem before. Anyway, edited.

Comment: So I tried it out a bit, and actually it only works when I omit the expression syntax (in opposition to what the documentation states). With the expression syntax the condition just always evaluates to `true` and the step is never skipped. Sorry for the confusion, it was just that the documentation stated this so strongly. Please remove it again from the answer :)

Comment: @Korthout I have edited the answer to clarify the expression syntax problem.